# python using lambda to change value in dict within list by conditions

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I'm looking  a way to use lambda or list comprehension to change a value in dictionary within a list

let's say i have a simple list with dictionaries

```
list_of_objects = [
 {'note': 'note1', 'comments': 'Test comments', elem': 1},
 {'note': 'note2','comments': None, elem': 2}
]
```

I need to iterate over this list, find each value in each dict with None and replace this value with text 'No comments was provided'

Expected result:

```
[{'note': 'note1',
  'comments': 'Test comments'
  'elem': 1},
 {'note': 'note2',
  'comments': 'No comments was provided'
  'elem': 2}]
```

and i could do it using standard for loop operation. But a'm looking opportunity to us lambda or list comprehension to minimize my code

Comment: `[{**d, 'comments': d['comments'] if d['comments'] is not None else 'No comments was provided'} for d in list_of_objects]` — Not sure that's really more readable than a simple `for` loop…

Answer (score 1):

see below (I think a for loop brings better readability)

```
list_of_objects = [
    {'note': 'note1', 'comments': 'Test comments', 'elem': 1},
    {'note': 'note2', 'comments': None, 'elem': 2}
]

lst = [{k: v if k != 'comments' else v if v else 'no comments' for k, v in entry.items()} for entry in
       list_of_objects]
print(lst)
```

output

```
[{'note': 'note1', 'comments': 'Test comments', 'elem': 1}, {'note': 'note2', 'comments': 'no comments', 'elem': 2}]
```